# How to run a retrofit in the background thread?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Interface:
I enter the word to text and then click on the button and in the output the result

```
public interface Link {
    @FormUrlEncoded//аннотация
    @POST("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate")
    Call<Object> translate(@FieldMap Map<String,String> map); 
}
```

[image]

How to run a retrofit in the background thread?

I enter the word to text and then click on the button and in the output the result,simple translator, I test this library

Comment: Exception name tells you everything.

Comment: @Vucko
I do not understand how to avoid, how to alter the code, read the documentation

Comment: use `enqueue()` instead of `execute()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce
 response = call.enqueue();
that passed to the method?

Comment: Well I'm sure you can figure that out on your own.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce
I just started to learn this library, please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431525/using-call-enqueue-function-in-retrofit

Comment: handling error response http://stackoverflow.com/a/32896077/2413303

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`call.execute();` is a synchronous network call which should not be performed on the main thread.
As they have pointed out to you, the best option you have is to use `call.enqueue()` like below:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
       response = response.body();
   }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {

  }
```

If the call is successful, you get your response in `onResponse` else in `onFailure`

Comment: i updated the topic,but not sure that my code correctly

Comment: Line 10 from the picture you posted,
1) You don't need to assign a variable response to the call i.e `response = ` is not needed.
Simply do `call.enqueue(...)` and get your response inside the `onResponse()` method.

See the edited answer above

Answer (score 1):

With com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call1, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {


            BufferedReader reader = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.body().byteStream()));
            String line;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            result = sb.toString();
          }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Tag","onResponse onFailure" );

        }
    });
```